# How to determine whether a triangle is obtuse angled or not from the equation of its sides?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, triangles, angle

Suppose we are given the equation of the sides of a triangle, how can we determine whether the triangle is obtuse angled or acute angled? In case of a right angled triangle, I would simply check whether the slopes $m_1$ and $m_2$ of any two lines follow the relation $m_1m_2=-1$. I know to find the angle between two intersecting lines with slopes $m_1$ and $m_2$ using the following formula:

$$\tan \theta = \left|\frac{m_2-m_1}{1+m_1m_2} \right|$$

The problem is, the above formula is helpful in finding only the positive values of the tangent function, or only for acute angles, due to the presence of the absolute value function.

Are there any other algorithm to distinguish acute angle triangles from obtuse angled triangles? Is it possible to use the same formula to find them?

Comment: Easiest way would be to look for the length of the sides and use the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to check is to see, whether the sum of angles calculated with your formula add up to $\pi$.

1. Consider $y=1-2x$, $y=1+2x$, $y=0$. Angles $\theta_{1,2,3}=1.107, 1.107,0.9273$. The sum $\sum\theta_i=\pi$. The triangle is acute
2. Consider $y=1-x/2$, $y=1+x/2$, $y=0$. Angles $\theta_{1,2,3}=0.4636, 0.4636, 0.9273$. The sum $\sum\theta_i=1.8545<\pi$. The triangle is obtuse.

*Edit.*
If you want to cope without calculator, you can utilize the formula for tangent of sum of 3 angles and derive the following criteria. If
$$
\left|\frac{1+m_1 m_2}{m_1-m_2}\right|\left|\frac{1+m_2 m_3}{m_2-m_3}\right| +
\left|\frac{1+m_2 m_3}{m_2-m_3}\right|\left|\frac{1+m_3 m_1}{m_3-m_1}\right| +
\left|\frac{1+m_3 m_1}{m_3-m_1}\right|\left|\frac{1+m_1 m_2}{m_1-m_2}\right| = 1,
$$
then the triangle is acute. If it's not, it is obtuse.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, how would I be able to calculate $\tan ^{-1}m$ for all values of $m$, in order to find $\theta_i$ ?

Comment: *calculate without using a calculator

Comment: I added a formula without trigonometry

Comment: I think if $A+B+C=\pi$ then $\tan A +\tan B +\tan C= \tan A \tan B \tan C$, and so must be the new expression introduced. Or you may use the half angles which will work with the existing ones.

Comment: My approach requires only $m_{1,2,3}$ and doesn't require finding the vertices first, lengths of sides second and cosine theorem next.

Comment: I understand that :) In my previous comment $A,B,$ and $C$ are angles and the conditional identity, i.e., when the sum of angles is $\pi$ then the one mentioned I mentioned will take place in case of complete angles, but the one mentioned by you as whole angles works for half angles (for example, $A/2$). I hope you understood me and kindly tell if I am wrong.

Comment: This is what I am trying to say: $$\left|\frac{1+m_1 m_2}{m_1-m_2}\right|+\left|\frac{1+m_2 m_3}{m_2-m_3}\right|+\left|\frac{1+m_3 m_1}{m_3-m_1}\right|=\left|\frac{1+m_1 m_2}{m_1-m_2}\right|.\left|\frac{1+m_2 m_3}{m_2-m_3}\right|.\left|\frac{1+m_3 m_1}{m_3-m_1}\right|$$

Comment: And not: $$
\left|\frac{1+m_1 m_2}{m_1-m_2}\right|\left|\frac{1+m_2 m_3}{m_2-m_3}\right| +
\left|\frac{1+m_2 m_3}{m_2-m_3}\right|\left|\frac{1+m_3 m_1}{m_3-m_1}\right| +
\left|\frac{1+m_3 m_1}{m_3-m_1}\right|\left|\frac{1+m_1 m_2}{m_1-m_2}\right| = 1,
$$ as per your answer. Am I correct? Kindly reply.

Comment: Just now realised that I was wrong. I did not notice that the individual expressions represent the cotangent and not the tangent function. Please ignore my previous comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: calculate $$a^2+b^2-c^2,a^2+c^2-b^2,b^2+c^2-a^2$$

Comment: It Comes from the Theorem of cosines: $$\cos(\gamma)=\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}$$

Comment: Thank you. I realised that only after typing my comment so I removed it.

Comment: If any one of the expressions turn out to be negative then it is a obtuse angled triangle, else it represents an acute angled triangle. If its zero then it is a right angled triangle. Could you please tell whether I am correct?

Comment: This is right my friend.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other method to determine this directly from the equation of the sides? I think finding the vertices and then applying distance formula will be a lengthy/time-consuming process.

Comment: I will think about your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this theorem
[a Theorem for classifying triangles when given only the slopes of the equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2919798/a-theorem-for-classifying-triangles-when-given-only-the-slopes-of-the-equations)

In order to know if a triangle is obtuse, acute or rectangle, one needs to know only the slopes of the equations of its sides.